# Treat empty string as NULL in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica, informatica-cloud

I am handling a migration project where our database is getting changed from Oracle 12c to Snowflake.

Currently there are many IICS (Informatica) integrations that load data into Oracle from different source systems and when it extracts an empty string from source systems, it would be treated and loaded as NULL in Oracle.

During the testing phase of database migration, we observed that empty string is treated as empty string itself in Snowflake and this is causing a lot of data comparison issues while doing reconciliation between Oracle and Snowflake data and other issues in the downstream.

Is there a way we can handle this scenario, wherein we can force Snowflake or IICS to treat empty string as NULL ? There are integration level functions to check the length of each field and perform validation but we are talking about hundreds of such integrations. I am looking for a global setting which can be applied on all the integrations or solution with minimal code changes. Any thoughts, suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you're loading your data into snowflake, but I think your best option here is to have your load process convert empty strings to null. That's the only option I can really think of where you don't have to specify per column.

For example, in COPY INTO statements (and by extension PIPEs), you can use the EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL option for your file formats. [See Format options here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions).

Comment: Data load is happening between SQL Server and Snowflake using ETL tool called Informatica Cloud. I am not quite sure how COPY INTO statements can be of help here.

Comment: I would hope that it's an option in the informatica tool. and under the hood I would expect it to be running a COPY INTO statement using that option. I'm not familiar with the specific tool though.

Answer (score 0):

You have two related options in [the COPY INTO command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html):

1. **NULL_IF** = ('', 'null', 'NULL') - by default '\\N'. When unloading data from Snowflake (in case you later upload it to Oracle), or loading data into Snowflake. What my sample here does is replacing any empty string, and 'null' or 'NULL' values (from a file when loading, or from a table when unloading) by an actual SQL NULL.
2. **EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL** = TRUE - by default TRUE. When loading data into Snowflake, a field like ",," (assuming comma as field separator) will be inserted as SQL NULL in the loading table, when the option is set. When unloading, use with FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY, to distinguish between empty strings and NULLs.

Comment: Data is getting extracted from SQL Server and loaded into Snowflake using ETL tool called Informatica Cloud. I think COPY INTO statements wont help us much here.

Comment: This is what they call under the hood: https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-mass-ingestion/current-version/mass-ingestion/mass-ingestion-files/configuring-a-file-ingestion-task/configuring-the-target/snowflake-cloud-data-warehouse-v2-target-properties/file-format-and-copy-options.html. These are all COPY INTO options, I bet the NULL-related are supported as well.